# Can't modify queue of object in array

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream>
#include<deque>
struct testStr {
    std::deque<int> queue;
};

testStr arr[1] = {
    testStr()
};

testStr t = testStr();

void func() {
    testStr s = arr[0];
    s.queue.push_back(5);
    t.queue.push_back(6);
}

void func2() {
    std::cout << arr[0].queue.empty() << ' ';
    std::cout << t.queue.empty() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    func();
    func2();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 0
```

I spent an hour tracking down this "bug" and don't understand why there's this behavior and how to overcome it. Appreciate any and all help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
testStr s = arr[0];
```

You copy `arr[0]` to a local variable `s`, then modify `s`, not `arr[0]`. In the same time `arr[0]` remains the same.

If you need to modify `arr[0]`, work with a reference:

```
testStr &s = arr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
testStr s = arr[0];
```

You are invoking the implicit copy constructor.  So the local variable `s` contains a copy of `queue` from `arr[0]`, not a reference to the same object.  So when you then do `s.queue.push_back(5);` you're only changing the local variable, not `arr[0]`.